# Game freezes for a second when player fires projectile in Sprite-kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-development, projectile

Game freezes for a second when the player fires the first bullet.

I'm trying to create a space shooter in Xcode. This is code I'm using to move the bullet once the player taps the screen.

```
 func fireLaser() {

    if(!canFire) {
        return
    } else {

        canFire = false

        let laserSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Shot 4.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)
        run(laserSound)

        laser = Projectile(imageNamed: "Laser_Medium")
        laser.name = "projectileName"
        laser.initalize()
        laser.position = player.position
        laser.position.y += 70
        laser.setScale(0.9)
        addChild(laser)

        let moveUp = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: player.position.x, y: 850), duration: 1)
        laser.run(moveUp)

        let waitToEnableFire = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.75)
        run(waitToEnableFire,completion:{self.canFire = true})
    }

}
```

The bullet is spawning and moving but freezes the game for a second the first time the bullet is fired.

Comment: I disagree with closing this question. He describes a specific problem and supplies code. There is a problem with Spritekit loading a sound file for the first time and temporarily pausing the game, try the code without the sound and see if you still have the same issue

Comment: Not off-topic. The problem is clearly explained and to those with sprite-kit experience, also fairly obvious. Recommend to re-open.

Comment: @Antwon - Every time you call your `fireLaser` function you are recreating `laserSound` SKAction from a file on disk - it's the initial disk access causeinghte delay - subsequently it's cached so no delay.. Create it once as a property in `didMoveTo(View:)` or similar setup function where you won;t notice the slight delay and then simply refer to the property each time.

Comment: Best of luck with your game